# RabbitMq PhpAmqpLib error 'Permission denied'

Tags: rabbitmq, redhat, php-amqplib

I have an error with PhpAmqpLib in my script:

```
[PhpAmqpLib\Exception\AMQPRuntimeException] 
Error Connecting to server (13): Permission denied (13)
```

I use it like this:

```
 $r = new PhpAmqpLib\Connection\AMQPConnection(
                'localhost',
                 5672,
                'guest',
                'guest'
            );
```

I tried many things like:

1) editing iptables and restarting it:

```
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5672 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5673 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 15672 -j ACCEPT
```

2) trying to check SELinux

```
semanage port -a -t http_port_t -p tcp 5672
/usr/sbin/semanage: Port tcp/5672 already defined
semanage port -l | grep 5672
amqp_port_t                    tcp      5671, 5672
amqp_port_t                    udp      5671, 5672
```

3) removing and installing erlang and rabbitmq again

but it didn't help.

Rabbitmq management plugin is worked, i can show information here:
127.0.0.1:15672

Rabbitmq server is also active.

```
rabbitmqctl status
Status of node rabbit@template ...
[{pid,30914},
 {running_applications,
     [{rabbitmq_management,"RabbitMQ Management Console","3.1.5"},
      {rabbitmq_management_agent,"RabbitMQ Management Agent","3.1.5"},
      {rabbit,"RabbitMQ","3.1.5"},
      {os_mon,"CPO  CXC 138 46","2.2.7"},
      {rabbitmq_web_dispatch,"RabbitMQ Web Dispatcher","3.1.5"},
      {webmachine,"webmachine","1.10.3-rmq3.1.5-gite9359c7"},
      {mochiweb,"MochiMedia Web Server","2.7.0-rmq3.1.5-git680dba8"},
      {xmerl,"XML parser","1.2.10"},
      {inets,"INETS  CXC 138 49","5.7.1"},
      {mnesia,"MNESIA  CXC 138 12","4.5"},
      {amqp_client,"RabbitMQ AMQP Client","3.1.5"},
      {sasl,"SASL  CXC 138 11","2.1.10"},
      {stdlib,"ERTS  CXC 138 10","1.17.5"},
      {kernel,"ERTS  CXC 138 10","2.14.5"}]},
 {os,{unix,linux}},
 {erlang_version,
     "Erlang R14B04 (erts-5.8.5) [source] [64-bit] [smp:8:8] [rq:8] [async-threads:30] [kernel-poll:true]\n"},
 {memory,
     [{total,32290312},
      {connection_procs,5408},
      {queue_procs,5408},
      {plugins,435992},
      {other_proc,9264648},
      {mnesia,59976},
      {mgmt_db,48480},
      {msg_index,34160},
      {other_ets,1110280},
      {binary,29664},
      {code,17472749},
      {atom,1567425},
      {other_system,2256122}]},
 {vm_memory_high_watermark,0.4},
 {vm_memory_limit,13149895065},
 {disk_free_limit,1000000000},
 {disk_free,2567311360},
 {file_descriptors,
     [{total_limit,924},{total_used,3},{sockets_limit,829},{sockets_used,1}]},
 {processes,[{limit,1048576},{used,199}]},
 {run_queue,0},
 {uptime,1099}]
...done.
```

I use Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5.

Maybe someone have any ideas what's cause of the problem?

p.s. I solved the problem by using:

```
/usr/sbin/setsebool httpd_can_network_connect=1
```

Comment: did you check the rabbitmq logs? `/var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@youmachine` to see if there is an error

Comment: i checked logs, but there are no errrors.